# Replacing function of a module with a custom one

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am working with an external module with a class `A` and function `foo`. The class calls the function inside it

```
def foo(...):
    ...

class A:
  def m(self, ...):
      ...
      foo()
      ...
  ...
```

I need to change the behavior of `foo` without editing the module. Is there a neat way to do it, without subclassing class `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the replacement function, then assign it to the class function.

```
def replacement_m(...):
    ...

from external_module import A
A.m = replacement_m
```

Unfortunately you can't just replace `foo()`, because it isn't a class method.  You have to replace the whole `A.m` method.

This is called *monkeypatching*.  See this question for more information [What is monkey patching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5626193/494134)

Comment: Considering that `foo()` can be seen as a module variable, can't I perform something similar to `module.foo = replacement_foo`?

Comment: Confirmed. I can perform the same monkey patching directly on a global function of a module (`foo` in my case). This changes the behavior of all class instances, also those that were istantiated *before* the patching.

Comment: @aretor Thanks for the info!